# C++ using array or vector for many items

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

The following code is an extract from a source code of a project about graph theory for the university (representation for the directed weighted graph):

```
struct Edge
{
  int neighboor : 20;
  int weight : 12;
} e;

struct Node
{
  double x;
  double y;

  vector<Edge> neighboors;
};

...

vector<Node> list;
list.resize(countNode);
```

Is there a way to save even more memory by replacing vector< Edge > with for example an array?
I'm thinking that there are thousands of vector< Edge > being created, and that takes a lot of memory, doesn't it?

Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some implementations of `std::vector`. can be pretty small. I know MSVC has done some work on that.

Comment: Thousands of vector is not so much.  The problem can be in the vectors size. How much memory is your program consuming?

Comment: at the moment about 50 MB for 300000 nodes (and vector<Edge>).
thanks for the response

Comment: So it's not an issue.

Comment: "Don't pre-optimize" is a very nice rule of thumb.

Comment: sizeof(list) = 24B. 24B * 300000 = 7200000B = 6.9 MB. 7MB of 50 MB only for the use of vector. My implementation is for Massachusetts, now its not an issue, but it could be one for USA for example...

Comment: @Jefffrey i just don´t know at the moment is it enough or not^^

Comment: Doesn't matter. You need at least |E| + |N| memory.  Each node is at least 16bytes, edge is at least 4bytes but 0<=|E|<|N|^2/2. 300,000 nodes = 1.2Mb already.  Even if you can get away with 4 byte edges, if you only have 10 edges per nodes for example, that's still 3Mb just for edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may share the vector of Edge for all nodes:

Something like:

```
struct Edge
{
  int32_t neighboor : 20;
  int32_t weight : 12;
} e;

struct Node
{
    double x;
    double y;
    int32_t indexInEdges : 28;
    int32_t neighboorCount : 4; // You may adjust these numbers
};

std::vector<Node> nodes;
std::vector<Edge> edges; // So edges contains the edges of nodes[0]
                         // then those of nodes[1] and so on.
```

You may also reduce the size of Node by using `float` instead of `double`

Comment: Keep in mind that this scheme is great when the graph is static, but scales awfully when edges are added.

Comment: @thiton: Agreed, performance to keep up to date the structure for dynamic graph is horrible.

Comment: i will try it later, but neighboorCount is not given. What i have is a file where its saved like:
node1 node2 weight

Comment: @user3167055: If edges are given in correct order, it would be ok.

Answer (score 2):

An array is an ordered collection with static length, and a vector is an ordered collection with dynamic length. Whether an array or a vector is the most memory-efficient data type for you depends on the number of elements that you intend to store. If all elements in the graph have the same number of edges, an array is more memory-efficient, because you get rid of the overhead for variable-length storage.

If the number of edges per element varies strongly, vector is definitely the better choice, because you don't have to statically over-allocate memory on every node for the edges that *might* be there, but aren't.

If you have small variation in the number of edges (say, 100 to 103 edges per element), an array might still be the better choice, because you can trade static overallocation for the overhead of both a dynamic allocation and the bookkeeping for the vector's size and capacity. Just how large this overhead is depends strongly on your vector implementation, and an experiment is the best way to decide whether it's worth it.

If an experiment seems too much hassle or if you don't have enough data for an experiment, don't overoptimize, and use the vector.

Answer (score 2):

If you use C++98 then you can save significant amount of memory by using arrays instead of `vector<Edge>` and `vector<Node>`. `vector`'s consume more memory than they actually needed because they reserve some additional memory for reducing number of memory relocation when a vector is growing.

If you use C++11 you can use `vector::shrink_to_fit()` to free the unused memory.

Comment: спасибо! I will try it, i am using  C++11.

Comment: I'm sorry but most probably `std::array<>` will not suit your needs because the array size must be defined at compile time. Anyhow you can use other two ways to save memory I mentioned.